# How to Convert int to Generics Type T

Tags: java, class, generics

I have a class with generic type.

It is nice and easy to add any type of object I want on Mylist using `addNode( )` since I am using generics. However, if I want to add in `(int) 5` **while I am in the class**. How am I able to do that? (See comment in below codes for example).

```
class MyList <T>
{
    Node <T> head = null;
    public void addNode(T element) {
        head = new Node <T> (element);
    }
    //Other methods removed for simplicity

    public void myMethod () {
        MyList <T> newList = new MyList <T>();

        //Below code generate error: required: T, found: int 
        newList.addNode(5);  //How to add an int 5 here when it is expecting Type:T?
    }
}

class Node <T>
{
    T element;
    public Node(T item) 
    { 
        element = item; 
    }
    //Other methods removed for simplicity
}
```

Comment: How can Java know that `T` will be bound to `Integer`?

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. How can we overcome this problem?

Comment: Declare your `newList` as `MyList<Integer> newList = ...`.

Comment: Will you be adding non `Integer` objects to your node(s)?

Comment: @Barranka no, only integers

Comment: then simply replace `T` with `Integer`

Comment: @Barranka, Sorry, Other than Integer, it will also add non-Integer objects of type T.

Comment: in the same `MyList<T>` object?

Comment: @Barranka Yes, in the same list.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> class MyList<T> {
>     // ...
>
>     public void addNode(T element) {
>         // ...
>     }
>
>     public void myMethod() {
>         MyList<T> newList = new MyList<T>();
>
>         newList.addNode(5);  // <- can't do that!
>     }
> }
> ```

*If you could* add an integer there, the class wouldn't be generic anymore. It would defeat the purpose.

In methods outside this class that use `MyList`, you could do this:

```
void another() {
    MyList<Integer> list = new MyList<Integer>();
    list.addNode(5);

    MyList<String> list2 = new MyList<String>();
    list.addNode("hello");
}
```

**UPDATE**

> What if I need to add both Integer and Nodes object into the list? Is there any way we can do it?

You *could* do this, but then, what's the template parameter is becoming pointless, and you are losing proper type checking features. Normally you shouldn't do this.

```
MyList<Object> list3 = new MyList<Object>();
list3.addNode(12);
list3.addNode("heya");
```

Comment: What if I need to add both Integer and Nodes object into the list? Is there any way we can do it?

Comment: I added another example, but I don't recommend to use it.

Comment: @janos In Java 8, you could make a POJO `Node` type and use two `Optional<T>` fields.